# Command parameters & arguments - Correct way of typing?

Tags: bash, arguments, parameter

Which is *the correct way* - to separate the argument from the parameter with a whitespace, or no?

*And* should you separate arguments or stick them all together?

Examples:

```
<command> -D 192.168.0.100 -p 80
<command> -cvvfz
```

or:

```
<command> -D192.168.0.100 -p80
<command> -c -vv -f -z
```

Do some programs accept only one "style", or does it matter at all, *generally speaking*?

Comment: It's entirely dependent on how `<command>` parses its arguments, so there's no general rule, but it is entirely *common* for such parsers to make the space separating a short option from its value to be optional.

Comment: Not worth an answer, but a nice example of lack of consistency not mentioned by any of the answers so far is [the `dd` command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dd), whose options are simply given as `key=value`, no hyphens in sight - except that GNU insist on all their utilities accepting `--help` and `--version`, regardless of any other option parsing they do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [blog](https://blog.heroku.com/cli-flags-get-started-with-oclif) can help you out.

A small fragment of this blog is here:

> ## Flag Argument
>
> Many flags accept an option called a "flag argument" (not to be
> confused with a "command argument"). In general a command's parameters
> can be in any order, but flags that accept options must have the
> option directly after the flag. That way, the command doesn’t get
> confused by non-flag arguments.
>
> For an example, here the -x flag does not accept an option but the -f
> flag does. archive.tar is the option being passed to -f. Both of these
> are valid.
>
> ```
> tar -x -f archive.tar
> tar -xf archive.tar
> ```
>
> A flag and its option can be
> separated by a space or an equals sign =. Interestingly, short flags
> (but not long flags) can even skip the space, although many people
> find it much easier to read with the space or equals sign. These three
> are all valid and equivalent.
>
> ```
> tar -f archive.tar
> tar -f=archive.tar
> tar -farchive.tar
> ```
>
> Long flags must have a space or equals sign to separate the flag from its option.
>
> ```
> git log --pretty=oneline git log --pretty oneline
> ```

Other resources:

1. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/307472

Comment: If they want to be correct, they should call it "option" and "option argument", not "flag" and "option" (or "flag option", or "flag argument"). Both options and option arguments are, together with operands (non-options sometimes listed after all options), arguments to the utility.

Comment: `tar -f=archive.tar` ... yeah, with GNU tar and the bsdtar on my Mac, that creates a file called `=archive.tar`, so no, that's not at all the same as the other two. For GNU-style long options, the equal sign works, so `tar --create --file=archive.tar hello.txt` creates `archive.tar`, if your `tar` supports that long option (so does `--file archive.tar`). I've never seen any utility where the equal sign would work with a short option, though.

Comment: I tend to think of a "flag" as a parameter that means "true" if it exists and "false" if it doesn't. I would not call a parameter that takes arguments a flag.

Answer (score 10):

Some programs *do* accept only one style. One or the other.

Anything that uses `getopt()` should accept both `-xfoo` and `-x foo` for option `-x` that takes an argument. However, not all programs use `getopt()`. *Optional* arguments are another thing yet, they might not work with `-x foo`, but may require `-xfoo`, because otherwise it would be hard to give options without the argument.

As for which one you "should" use, that's a question of preference where everyone is likely to have their own opinion.

Answer (score 6):

Some programs require one style, others don't. For example:

```
mysql -ph 10.1.1.1
```

will make `mysql` try to connect to `localhost` with password `h`.

```
mysql -p -h 10.1.1.1
```

on the other hand will connect to `10.1.1.1` and prompt for password.

Comment: The lack of standards can be mind-numbing at times.

Answer (score 5):

That is up to the utility to define. Some accept one or both of the forms.

In [POSIX utility conventions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html), the argument syntax section gives this template

```
utility_name[-a][-b][-c option_argument]
    [-d|-e][-f[option_argument]][operand...]
```

and requires that option-arguments
be separated from their options by blank characters, except when the option-argument
is optional, in which case no separation should be used. *But* then...

> there are some exceptions in POSIX.1-2017 to ensure continued operation of historical applications.

and in the next section, utility syntax guidelines, guideline 7 says that
option-arguments should not be optional.

If one thing is clear from all that confusion is that there is not anything near
a written in stone rule about the blanks between flags and arguments.

Concrete examples to get the message accross:

```
Syntax error                        Syntactically correct
xclip -ir <<< ABC                   xclip -i -r <<< ABC
xkbcomp -I /home/user "main" :0     xkbcomp -I/home/user "main" :0
rename -e's/f/x/' f                 rename -e 's/f/x/' f
```

<sup>As a side-note, notice guideline 3 says "each option name should be a single alphanumeric character".
You can come up with a ton of examples of utilities that use multi-character option names.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the program but *generally* there must be a space between an option and its value.

Some applications/utilities accept `--option=value` parameters in which case there mustn't be a space.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers above, and their exceptions, programs written in go tend to use the convention started (I believe) by plan9, what seems like long options with only one dash.  Also a lot of the original X programs (even vncserver) use one dash, like xterm -geometry 80x24+10+10 for example.

Basically I would say you have to examine each program individually to verify which style they use.  Although the gnu long and short option style seems to be more prevalent now, except for the new go programs.